# Why would a SQL query return rows un-ordered even with an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

Everything I've read says this shouldn't happen, but it happens. My database is roughly 15GB in size, few hundred tables, tables can have anywhere from a few rows to a few million.

Here is what happens: Let's say I have a table called `orders` and the first column is called `ID` and is the primary key for the table. There are many other columns, one of which is named `policy`. If I run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE policy = 12345 
ORDER BY ID
```

I would expect the result to look something like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But sometimes the result will look like this:

```
1
2
4
5
3
6
```

It's as if the `3` was moved to a different position. How/why would this happen?

The actual query is

```
SELECT * FROM loc_info WHERE PolInfo_ID=25634 ORDER BY LocInfo_ID
```

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loc_info]( 
    [LocInfo_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [PolInfo_ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL, 
    [address1] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [address2] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [city] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [state] [varchar](100) NOT NULL, 
    [zip] [char](10) NULL, 
    [county] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [country] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [loc_number] [varchar](20) NULL, 
    [occ_type_id] [int] NULL, 
    [occ_type] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [flood_zone] [varchar](6) NOT NULL, 
    [coastal_zone] [varchar](20) NOT NULL, 
    [earthquake_zone] [varchar](20) NOT NULL, 
    [earthquake_group] [varchar](20) NULL, 
    [BuildingTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [MachEquipTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [StocksSuppliesTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [OtherTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [BusinessInterruptTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [ExtraExpTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [RentTIV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [Property] [numeric](18, 0) NULL, 
    [IsUpload] [bit] NULL, 
    [IsMoved] [bit] NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_locations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
( 
    [LocInfo_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF
, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] 
)
```

Comment: What **datatype** is the `ID` column?

Comment: Where are you consuming the result? Is orders a *view* or a *table*?

Comment: it's weird, even if the data type is string, 3 should always follow 2. unless you have 21 which is a string.

Comment: Does the `ID` column ever get updated?

Comment: This happens just by running the query in the management studio.

Comment: Can you show us the table design?

Comment: @Martin I didn't ask if the query in the question was a view or a table (it obviously can't be a table). I was asking if the `orders` object was a view.

Comment: No views are being used.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Fair point!

Comment: And are you absolutely positive that the column that you are showing us is `ID`?, cause I see a `SELECT *` in there

Comment: I'd run a DBCC CHECKDB, weirder things have happened with corrupt data :)

Comment: @Lamak it's actually called `LocInfo_ID` but it's the PK for the table.

Comment: Is this the actual query you execute? Are possibly some joins involved?

Comment: @EscobarCeaser it's one thing that it's the PK of the table, what I want to know if is it is the same column that you are using on the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Is this query used in a table valued function? I got bit on that once-assumed the data coming out of the function was sorted because I had the ORDER BY clause in the function but `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTVF` would result in an unordered set.

Comment: Please post the actual table definition, and the actual query.

Comment: I don't really care. The answer here is that this should not be possible, and if it is happening, it is a bug. People want to down-vote that as an answer, fine, have fun.

Comment: @Lamak yes that is the ORDER BY column. Here is the actual query: `SELECT * FROM loc_info WHERE PolInfo_ID=25634 ORDER BY LocInfo_ID`

Comment: Here is the table: https://www.dropbox.com/s/46wa1dywqal3zjx/SNAG-0000.png

Comment: You need to provide a repro, not a screen shot of a table designer.

Comment: Can you supply the `CREATE TABLE` including indexes?

Comment: And (sorry for keep saying this), can you post a pic of the actual results ordered that way with the column names?

Comment: @MartinSmith here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k17m4ld9yft79hm/table.sql

Comment: @EscobarCeaser No this is easy to do.  Post: **The CREATE table** including any indexes, the **query** and the **output**.

Comment: Man, I still want to see a screenshot of that query with those results, so I can see the column names

Comment: @Lamak unfortunately this doesn't happen all the time. It's seemingly random.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser - OK. The column is `IDENTITY` which probably rules out concurrent data modifications as being a possible cause.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser Then please take a screenshot when it happens again to make sure that this issue is actually happening

Comment: @Lamak while I appreciate the help, I assure you this isn't an issue where I'm seeing things. This was brought to my attention by one of my DBAs. He has seen it several times, as has other high level technical employees. But I will indeed get a screenshot asap.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser - Also if you manage to reproduce this issue please capture the actual execution plan.

Comment: OK, folks, this argument is getting a little out of hand. I've scrubbed the worst of it here, but let's keep this on topic please.

Comment: I've had similar issues a long time ago, i believe with SQL Server 2000. It was a very large table, and simple selects to it gave odd results. I don't remember exactly the cause, but it was something that was broken. Check for corrupt indexes, faulty hardware, etc.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser That type of result on SQL Server 2000 is *more probable* than SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Seriously? 32 comments and down votes?

Comment: @dbf the premise is wrong, and the question is incomplete ("this one time, at band camp, my order by came out in the wrong order, but it doesn't happen now, and I can't prove it ever happened"). You also missed some fun in the comments.

Comment: This question is terribly confusing and poorly written due to a few reasons, one being that there is a code sample included that would not even compile given the presented schema. What's more is that it the schema was provided late in the game. Finally, steps to reproduce haven't been identified (and, as a result, not presented)

Answer (score 9):

This should not be possible, assuming that the column you're ordering by is actually `LocInfo_ID`, it is truly an `INT`, and you really do have an `ORDER BY` clause in place when the issue happens.

If you can produce a valid repro where those three conditions are true, you would have a bug on your hands (possibly caused by corruption).

I suspect there are other variables here that we don't know about. My guess is that the column you're inspecting is not the one you're ordering by, or it is not the data type you think it is, or when you observe this random unordered result, there isn't actually an order by being used.

SQL Server doesn't mess up an `ORDER BY` that you've defined unless (a) you didn't define it or (b) you didn't define it in a way that produces the order you expect. The chances that you've uncovered a bug in SQL Server are very small indeed.

Comment: I'm looking at the table design right now. `LocInfo_ID` is (pk, int, not null).

Comment: Well you're wrong about something that you have described. Or, you have hit a bug in SQL Server. No offense, but my money's on the former.

Comment: Yes. Myself and 2 other highly skilled DBAs are "wrong about something we described." That sounds very likely.

Comment: @Escobar I agree. Now, do you want help solving this problem, or not?

Comment: @EscobarCeaser Aaron is a valuable resource (Microsoft DEFCON 5 MVP) . He was not attacking you or your skills.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're looking to complicate things. This is a terribly simple query on an even simpler table, that produces odd results at times. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser You really need to do what MartinSmith said and retrieve the actual execution plan if this happens again

Comment: @Escobar, what this answer is basically saying is ***"if this happens, it's a bug."*** You may bet on one thing and Aaron on another. That doesn't change that and no-one is saying you are seeing things.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser I'm not trying to complicate anything. I'm trying to help point out what variables may exist that could lead to the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser What's more likely - that a very obvious bug exists in the `ORDER BY` code in a database product that has millions of installs that nobody else has ever noticed, or that there is something particular in your situation that is causing this to appear like a bug but is actually an unintended consequence of something else in your query?

Comment: @JackPettinger please don't edit other people's answers unless there is something valuable to contribute. Let me write the way I want. If you want to contribute to this question so badly, why don't you post an answer instead of stomping over everyone else?

Comment: "Stranger things have happened." @EscobarCeaser in the world of SQL server stranger things have not happened. An order by not ordering by what you told it too is pretty strange. I need some sort of concrete example of this happening or I don't buy that it is. If this is a SQL bug but you can't re-create it seems peculiar. All we have to go off of at this moment is you saying sometime this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ORDER BY LocInfo_ID desc`?  Just to make sure it really is LocInfo_ID that is being sorted?  Will the 3 ever be out of place then?  There seems to be some thought (mine included) that this query is embedded within something else or included as part of a CTE or TVF -- you've yet to upload an execution plan.